# Loss of power ubuntu 16.04 dual boot Win 10 OK

Tags: dual-boot, power-management

I have my Acer 5610 laptop set up for dual booting with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. When using Ubuntu the power-on light will start flashing and the power shuts off during normal operation. This a random thing, it happens several times every day. When operating with Windows 10 There is no problem and the computer dos not shut off. What the heck is going on with this? Another thing is that after restarting the audio is disabled and a second restart is required to re-establish the sound.

Comment: You could either 1) have a temperature problem and the computer is shutting itself down to protect the hardware, or 2) your system is hard crashing. In the `terminal` app, type `ls -alt /var/crash` and `grep temp /var/log/syslog*` and edit your question to include that output.

Comment: My guess is also #1. The main problem of an Acer Aspire 5610 in 2016/7 is (very) old age so everything is possible.  When in Windows the problem may not be triggered - it all depends on the workload - but that doesn't mean it isn't there. Try running a graphics demanding modern game in Windows (most likely it'll crash even faster).

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your input. My system doesn't understand The -alt command. I did however get results with the second  command of  "grep temp /var/log/syslog. The results are copied and pasted. I do not understand all I should know about the results.

Comment: I cannot paste it in the comment window, too many characters. Can we email each other?

Comment: I do not play game other than solitaire.  I do however like videos and music from You Tube. When I use Windows and access You Tube there is no problem. The laptop doesn't seem to generate more heat with on system or the other. I have installed a new mother board, a 5610, replacing a 5610Z to take advantage of additional memory not supported by the 5610Z board. I am suspicious of the ALSA driver installed automatically with the 16.04 software. When using ver 14.04, I had to install the ALSA driver from another source and There were no problems with it. I do not recall where I found the driver

Comment: From what I've read, Acers are notorious for brittle solder connections, causing failures after a few years. You could try baking the motherboard.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for trying to help me. The laptop eventually started doing the blinking power on light when trying to boot up in Windows. After this happened at the next attempt to boot up. The computer'system told me I do not have an Acer power supply and it didn't like that one bit!  I did replace the supply a long time ago with "one Supply fit all" power supply". This strikes me a odd because it has worked for years on the supply. But then I did replace the motherboard and it apparently does not like the supply. Problem solved.